# Select which Dropbox account to synchronize with when camera upload is on

Tags: sync, camera, dropbox

I installed Dropbox on my rooted Samsung Galaxy SIII that runs Android 4.1.2.

I have 2 Dropbox accounts, one personal, one Dropbox account for business. When turning on the camera upload, how can I choose which account to use? I would like to choose the Dropbox account for business ("MIT" in my case), not the "Personal" account as by default.

My 2 accounts:

[image]

Turning on the camera upload:

[image]

I don't see anything in the settings:

[image]